# Есть ли какие-то ограничения на получение репутации в день?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Есть ли какие-то ограничения на получение репутации в день? - хочу уточнить ее правила начисления

Comment: Нет ограничений, +15 за принятый ответ, +10 за обычный плюсик, -2 за минус Вашего ответа

Comment: @entithat не больше 200 в день вроде бы

Comment: @СергейМишин, ага, действительно *В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий. Конкурсы, принятые ответы и бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов не ограничены дневным пределом репутации.*. Я просто максимум 180+ получал :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Я получал больше 500 ограничений нет

Comment: @AzizUmarov присутствует ограничений в 200 репутации, полученные за 20 голосов «за», а принятые ответы и вознаграждение не учитываются

Comment: @Danis ответ на конкурсный вопрос

Comment: Тут похоже кто-то балуется накруткой репутации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/420745/6apaiii?tab=reputation
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPiSF.png . Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что накрученные голоса завтра опять откатятся, а при злоупотреблении вы получите бан?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За голоса за и против - до 200 в день.

Помимо этого неограниченно за принятые ответы и награды в конкурсах.

Ещё единоразово +100 за ассоциацию учётной записи.

Comment: Всё верно: 180 за +/- и 60 за принятые. Итого 240 за день.

Comment: @UModeL -- 605 -- видел и больше у людей репы за день без всяких конкурсов, [чисто на ответах](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ4Pr.png)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, 28*15 = 420.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот же [605](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation) 14 декабря или я чего-то не понимаю. Видимо набор идет за счет, как ты и указал принятsх ответов +15